# Why would a Seagate Wireless Plus appear twice in Seatools (SAS-SCSI-FC & USB-1394)

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, diagnostic

I just received an RMA drive back from Seagate and I believe this one too could be faulty. I have fired up SeaTools but a little confused which device is correct as it appears twice. I assume that both are correct but would like to know why the device appears twice as:

- SAS-SCSI-FC
- USB 1394

I suspect that the SAS one is the actual drive within the closure of the device and the USB 1394 is the controller card within the device but a little confused why it would display both and which one is the one you should use to test the drive.

*They have the same serial number but one has 3 characters more like so:*

[image: SeaTools]

The real serial numbers have been removed and replaced with similar dummy ones for RMA purposes.

Question(s):

- Why does the device appear twice?
- Which one should do run the test on?

Comment: "Which one should do run the test on?" It shouldn't make any difference (but only one may be testable). I have an external USB Seagate drive which also appears twice in some SMART test programs. In my case only one of them is testable ...

Comment: It allows me to do both, both seem to work. So is the test exactly the same? Seems odd that one would be USB and the other as SAS.

Comment: Inspecting the drive information within SeaTools they contain the same information but the USB shows one more sector and not the speed of the device, the sass show one less sector and does show the connection speed.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the USB HID device drivers that the drive was developed to use.

I assume that the drive you used was connected up using USB. Then naturally Seatools detected it as a USB drive.

However, the manufacturer also allows their drives to be used as virtual SAS, SCSI and FC drives to satisfy the various needs of users. Hence, that was when Seatools detects the other drive with the label SAS-SCSI-FC for obvious reason.